# Netbeans 8.2 with JDK9 BUILD160

Tags: netbeans-8, java-9, netbeans-8.2

I'm trying to add "JDK9 Build 160" as a platfrom in netbeans 8.2. After adding the platform, the class tab contains no platform classpaths. I tried many blogs and guides but gave no solution. Could someone help please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Netbeans 8.2 with jdk 9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41230488/netbeans-8-2-with-jdk-9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that JDK 9 does not work with NetBeans 8.2.  To use JDK 9 Early Access builds you will need one of the NetBeans daily development builds.  Have a look at the wiki page that explains it in a lot more detail:

http://wiki.netbeans.org/JDK9Support

I've used the daily development builds and JDK 9 with no problems.  With the development build the 'Classes' tab will display all of the platform modules included in JDK 9 as part of the JPMS.